# Golang regexp with non-latin characters

Tags: regex, go

I am parsing words from some sentences and my `\w+` regexp works fine with Latin characters. However, it totally fails with some Cyrillic characters.

Here is a sample app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func get_words_from(text string) []string {
    words := regexp.MustCompile("\\w+")
    return words.FindAllString(text, -1)
}

func main() {
    text := "One, two three!"
    text2 := "Раз, два три!"
    text3 := "Jedna, dva tři čtyři pět!"
    fmt.Println(get_words_from(text))
    fmt.Println(get_words_from(text2))
    fmt.Println(get_words_from(text3))
}
```

It yields the following results:

```
 [One two three]
 []
 [Jedna dva t i ty i p t]
```

It returns empty values for Russian, and extra syllables for Czech.
I have no idea how to solve this issue. Could someone give me a piece of advice?

Or maybe there is a better way to split a sentence into words without punctuation?

Comment: try `regexp.MustCompile("\\p{L}+")`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `\w` shorthand class only matches ASCII letters in [GO regex](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/), thus, you need a Unicode character class `\p{L}`.

> `\w`             word characters (== `[0-9A-Za-z_]`)

Use a character class to include the digits and underscore:

```
    regexp.MustCompile("[\\p{L}\\d_]+")
```

Output of the [demo](http://play.golang.org/p/fWfI58QEEq):

```
[One two three]
[Раз два три]
[Jedna dva tři čtyři pět]
```

Comment: Ouu, I see. Just a habit of using \w, while I need word. My bad. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bonus - if you use backticks, you don't have to double-escape:  ```regexp.MustCompile(`[\p{L}\d_]+`)```

Comment: Yes, I posted this when I was not aware of raw [string literals in Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).